# Eliminating Redundancy with (Multiple) Nested For-Loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```py
for x in range(10):
  for y in range(10):
    for z in range(10):
      if (1111*x + 1111*y + 1111*z) == (10000*y + 1110*x + z):
        print(z)
```

Is there a way to shorten this code, specifically the first 3 lines where I've used three similar looking for loops? I'm quite new to python so please explain any modules used, if possible.

Comment: @toolic I'm sorry, but it's not a good question for Code Review at all. There is no description and no context, two things we require before starting a review. Please [be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/1014587).

Comment: Why are X, Y, Z all in that range? Is that by accident of because of some rule? If you have such a rule then you can use that to figure out how to simplify. If there isn't then maybe the code should stay as it is...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're essentially evaluating a function in a 3d coordinate system, with coordinates given by x, y, and z. So let's look at Numpy, which implements arrays in Python. If you're familiar with matlab or IDL, these arrays have similar functionality.

```
import numpy
x = numpy.arange(10) #Same as range but creates an array instead of a generator
y = numpy.arange(10)
z = numpy.arange(10)

#Now build a 3d array with every point
#defined by the coordinate arrays
xg, yg, zg = numpy.meshgrid(x,y,z)

#Evaluate your functions
#and store the Boolean result in an array.
mask = (1111*xg + 1111*yg + 1111*zg) == (10000*yg + 1110*xg + zg)

#Print out the z values where the mask is True
print(zg[mask])
```

Is this more readable? Debatable. Is it shorter? No. But it does leverage array operations which may be faster in certain circumstances.